# React Native: Failed to install on any devices

Tags: react-native

I just started studying React Native. I did all the Android SDK setup and tested everything using Android studio. Using Android Studio, the Hello World app works and runs on my phone with no errors.
However, I followed every step it takes to run my React Native app on my Android phone:

1. Enabled USB debugging on my phone
2. Checked the "Allow installs from unknown sources" on my phone
3. I plugged in my phone and did all the setting about device ID
4. But when I run my app (which was created using `react-native init AwesomeProject`), I get the following error.

When I run `react-native run-android`, I get this:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
> Failed to install on any devices.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1 mins 20.824 secs Could not install the app on the
>   device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an
>   Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your
>   Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

When I run `adb devices`, I get this:

> adb server is out of date.  killing...
>   * daemon started successfully * 
>   List of devices attached   ????????????   no permissions 
>   emulator-5554 device

I don't care that the app isn't running even on the emulator-5554 device that seems to have no problem. What I want is for the app to run on my phone which appears to be the app listed as `????????????   no permissions`. 
I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you tried to run the android emulator ?

Comment: Open your Android Studio and Run you emulator.Then in your command prompt/terminal navigate to the project directory and run "react-native run-android"

Comment: I ran the command `react-native run-android` when the emulator was already running. It didn't run on the emulator. Like I said in the question, I'm not particularly interested in getting it to run on the emulator.

Comment: try to change your data cable it seems you are using charge only data cable charge only cable are not mean to debug an app and you can not identify these cable physically

Answer (score -2):

You must setup android virtual device (AVD) in Android Studio first before you can  `react-native run-android`.

Other than that, you can also run standalone android avd via Terminal(Mac) / CMD (Window) with the command `android avd` and setup AVD there. After the simulator has run, then you can run `react-native run-android`

NOTE: Read the whole RN android setup guide

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.24/docs/android-setup.html